# Angular $http callbacks not working for HTTP 304 in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, http, cache-control

I am encountering a problem with Angular 1.5 and I could not find a similar question via Google. For a welcome change, the problem does not exist in IE, it only happens in the latest version of Chrome.

When I approach a JSON API and I send the same `GET` request twice in a row, the first request returns a `200 OK` and the second returns a `304 NOT MODIFIED`. I am doing the request with `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'` to simulate how our (generated) API client performs requests. With cache control *enabled*, both requests are executed correctly (see F12) and the program terminates. With cache control *disabled*, both requests are executed correctly (F12) but the program does not terminate.

Is this a bug in Chrome, or a bug in Angular's `$http`, or am I missing some crucial detail?

[Minimal example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mdheuay/)

Output:

```
Hi
Sending request 1 to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1...
Success 1!
Resolved 1!
Sending request 2 to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1...
```

Comment: requests are resolved for me on latest chrome. (just updated)

Comment: @gyc: just upgraded from 52.0.2743.116 to 53.0.2785.89, but I still get the same output. What version are you using?

Comment: 53.0.2785.89 with an 'm' at the end

Comment: Same here, it does end in an m... I wonder why it behaves differently on your end. I asked a colleague and he has the same problem as me. @Everyone: if it works for you please upvote gyc's comment.

Comment: Seems to work now on 53.0.2785.101 m. Magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after a Google Chrome update.